# chat server in heroku

Tags: python, html, django

I have this chat server I normally run with `./manage.py run_chat_server`. I recently deployed my app to Heroku and I can't figure out how to run the `chat_server`. can I get help
I have tried with the console in Heroku but I just realized that it does not run the `manage.py` command since it tells me command not found.

Comment: Where do you have your `run_chat_server` command? You should use gunicorn or uWSGI on a server.

Comment: Did you try `python ./manage.py run_char_server` or `python manage.py run_char_server`?

Comment: bojan kogoj - there is a dir called magement with run_chat_server.py i am using the private chat server from this link https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/tree/dev/django_private_chat in github

Comment: yes webyneter I already tried that one

Comment: okey I was missing out somethng the python manage.py run_chat_server  is now working but the app is not yet able to send messages when I send messages. I now believe there are some configuration to be done in heroku. who has ever used heroku to tell me how to add dynos becouse I think that is the thing or anything to be added if not dynos

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an application with django-private-chat running on Heroku. The key was to run the chat service as a separate Heroku web app. I deployed two versions of the application to separate Heroku apps, only changing the Procfile.

Here are what each Procfile looks like

```
#Chat Service Procfile
web: python manage.py run_chat_server
```

```
#Django Application Procfile
web: gunicore <app_name>.wsgi
```

The settings I used were:

```
#settings.py

CHAT_WS_SERVER_HOST =  '0.0.0.0'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'wss'
CHAT_WS_SERVER_PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5002))
```

In addition, I modified the `var base_ws_server_path = ‘wss://<chat-service-app-name>.herokuapp.com/'` in templates>django_private_chat>dialogs.html.

Let me know if you have any questions.